# Seaside: Instantiate and Render a Component via RESTful api

Tags: rest, smalltalk, seaside

I'd like to expose a component of my seaside application using a restful api. I read the REST chapter of the seaside book and did not learn how to instantiate and render one of my components from a restful filter. For example, suppose I have a filter method on a subclass of WARestfulFilter, how do I fill in the blanks? Note that I am nervous about [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862769/rest-service-in-seaside-smalltalk) as I want my rendered callbacks to work too.

```
Myfilter>>showDocument: name
   <get>

  | component |
  component := MyComponent named: name.
  "__how to render this?__"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want it to provide a meaningful url to a component, using SeasideREST (which is not originally made for that).

But, you can check this thread: http://forum.world.st/Seaside-and-urls-td4721764.html

I provide there a way to do what you want, by tweaking the SeasideREST implementation and purpose :)

Comment: Thank you, I am reading the thread. One worry is this comment: "I will pass aBlock to the root class of app, which I assume is a REApplication. Otherwise, this will fail" I don't see the class REApplication in my system, is it really needed?

Comment: Regarding contentComponent -- is this a "wrapper" component you are using in your own code?

Comment: Ah, that comment is because I copy&pasted from my app. Not really needed.

Comment: and yes... contentComponent is a component I'm using in the app.

Comment: is 'application trackingStrategy' something you added as well? I don't see it in my image.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer looks like realistic when it comes to callbacks.

If you do REST, callbacks shouldn't work IMHO.

But nobody precludes you from generating URIs that are meaningful for your component when called again.

Maybe a configuration setting in MyComponent would do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the previous answer is correct in that I should not be able to expose callbacks on a page with a public-facing (sessionless) url? And when you say nobody precludes me, are you saying there is a simple answer to my question? If so, what is it?